If the Levities killed the 3000, why did Moses say he had to go to God on the Israelites behalf for their sin?
If the Levites killed 3000 according to scripture, why did Moses still say they had sinned a great sin so he was going to God on their behalf and hopefully they would be forgiven?
This situation begins in Exodus 32:7,8 and continues to the end of the chapter, where only the Levites responded to Moses to take up arms.

And the Lord said to Moses, “Go, get down! For your people whom you
brought out of the land of Egypt have corrupted themselves. They have
turned aside quickly out of the way which I commanded them. They have
made themselves a molded calf, and worshiped it and sacrificed to it,
and said, ‘This is your god, O Israel, that brought you out of the
land of Egypt!’”


@ user 117704 - To best answer your question please add the specific Scripture verse as a reference.  Thanks for asking your question. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul! Peace

The scripture text in question is Exodus 32:25-35. The particular verse about the Levites killing around 3,000 Israelites is verse 28, and the verse about Moses seeking God's forgiveness for the many more thousands of Israelites remaining is verse 30. It's always a good idea for the person asking the question to state the exact Bible reference, and to quote it in full. It took me a while to track the verses down, but as I'm retired, and I've got all day, that doesn't matter.

"And the children of Levi did according to the word of Moses: and
there fell of the people that day about three thousand men." Exodus
32:28 A.V.
"And it came to pass on the morrow, that Moses said unto the people,
Ye have sinned a great sin: and now I will go up into the Lord;
peradventure I shall make an atonement for your sin." Ibid. vs.30

The simple answer is that the number of Israelites who sinned by getting a golden calf idol to prance around in idolatrous worship like the pagans, numbered far more than 3,000 men.
Moses sought God's forgiveness for the vast crowd remaining, and part of the answer he received from God was that:

"Mine angel shall go before thee, nevertheless in the day when I visit
I will visit their sin upon them. And the Lord plagued the people,
because they had made the calf, which Aaron made." Ibid. vss. 34-35

This shows how seriously God views - and deals with - idolatry. Those idolators who did not fall by the swords of men from the tribe of Levi (the Levites) later experience a plague from heaven. But the zeal of the Levites caused them to be set apart unto God, to be caretakers of the tabernacle, and assistants to the priests.
Their zeal reminds us of the zeal of Aaron's grandson, Phinehas. See Numbers 25:1-13 for how Phinehas's action stemmed a plague on the nation at that time, when 24,000 Israelites died due to more idolatry. God then made an everlasting covenant for the priesthood with Phinehas.
The more fulsome answer is that all sin is so serious, that God has to either punish all sin, or - if sinners repent - forgive that sin totally. This is where a mediator needs to step in, on behalf of the sinning people. Moses did that for the remaining Israelites back then, so that they were not all wiped out. Phinehas's zeal caused him to mediate at another time when idolatry had caused the whole nation to sin once more, a plague from God striking them. Had Phinehas not acted, the whole nation would have continued to suffer that plague.
